# Questions about the ADT Tree in java

Tags: java, interface, tree, adt

I have an exam coming up and one of the topics is this:

Abstract datatypes: Queue, Deque, stacks, trees

My question is: What is trees? Since it is not an interface, like the 3 others, what do you think is meant by "trees"? Is it something about what "treeset" and "treemap have in common or?

I would really appreciate if someone could help me out here..

Comment: Stack (from java.util) is not an interface.

Comment: If your question is What is Tree data structure, see it wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28data_structure%29.  And this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12468981/tree-implementation-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might refer to the ADT group of trees, which may come up in very different implementations and thus, runtime behaviours. ADTs generally mean a more abstract (not in the sense of Java) concept. Best way is to look at the concept of Queue, Deque, Stack and (Binary-)Trees. A good place to start is probably [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_data_type), especially the data structures table at the end of the article, where the details of the data structures are explained. As you can see, there are a lot of tree ADTs, and that's only the tip of the iceberg.

Once you understood the way they work, read the Java API. You may want to read docs of LinkedList, ArrayList, HashMap and HashSet, TreeMap and TreeSet, which are the most used ADT implementations in Java.

By the way better omit the Java implentations Hashtable and Vector which are not used anymore, as they are `synchronized` on every single operation, which is most probably not what you want (it's bulk synchronisation).